# Run a middleware before Nest Js ServeStaticModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, middleware

I want to run a middleware before Nest JS serves my React application using ServeStatic Module. I cannot get a nest middleware or even a Global middleware to run on any static routes other than '/'

`main.ts`

```js
app.use([AuthRedirectMiddleware, VerifyMiddleware]);

// Or even a simple logger

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   console.log("LOG: ", req.originalUrl);
   next();
});

// All 3 middlewares only run for / and /api*
// Does not run for /posts , /orders/123 (both are front end routes)
```

This is only working for API routes and '/'

My static serve module is setup like this:

`app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: clientPath,
      exclude: ["/api*"],
    }),
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```

I also have a globalPrefix for api routes in main.js. So all urls except for `/api*` go to the react application

```js
 app.setGlobalPrefix("api");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a middleware module:

my-middleware.module.ts

```
@Module({}) // you can import/provide anything you need in your module here
export class MyMiddlewareModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(MyMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
    }
}

@Injectable()
class MyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: (error?: any) => void) {
    
    }
}
```

and then import it in your `app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MyMiddleware, // Important for it to be before your static module
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: clientPath,
      exclude: ["/api*"],
    }),
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```

Also these two links maybe useful:

- https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1248
- https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#request-lifecycle

Comment: This does not work for me. The middleware runs for all '/' and '/api*' routes but not for any other front end route. I believe this has got to do something with the front end reatc routing. for instance '/about` is being served by index.html but this route is not being fired in any middlewares. Even opening in incognito directly skipping js routing.

Comment: React has its own router, and because it's client-side-rendered, it works completely on the client's browser, so nothing will get to your server running NestJS, so the middleware cannot fire!

My answer was for when you are serving a static file using NestJS, like an image

Comment: If I open a url like `/about` in incognito without any cache, before serving the index.html, the middleware is supposed to run which does not happen.